# Python Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting below error when running 'import transformers', even though I have installed in the same vitual env. I'm using python 3.8

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'
```

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B3Sb.png)

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it using 'pip3 install transformers' from python cmd line.

Then I tried to uninstalled again, and reinstalled in jupyter notebook using '!pip install transformers', result shows '

```
Installing collected packages: transformers
Successfully installed transformers-4.24.0
```

'

I can also verify directly in Jupyter Notebook:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WyEm.png)

I tried to  install transformers successfully in jupyter Notebook. After that still getting `ModuleNotFoundError` error (have tried restarted kernel too)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAxgb.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did your restart the ipython kernel between install/uninstall? Does this only affect Jupyter notebooks, or does the same error occur if you use `python` in the console? Do examples from the documentation also raise this error? (e.g.: `from transformers import pipeline`)

Comment: Also, please copy the text of all error messages into the question. [Screenshots of code are useless when searching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: this seems like a python interpreter proble. You may have multiple installations of python and are installing the package into a python version that you aren't using

Comment: And although it may not help because of the many versions, for a better experience going forward you'd want to not use an exclamation point with `pip install` when running in a notebook. The magic command `%pip install` was added to insure installation to the environment backing the kernel underlying the running notebook. Use of the exclamation point alone doesn't handle that. See about `%pip install` (and related `%conda install` for users using conda for package management) [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes  I restarted Jupyter notebook between install/uninstall, if that's what you mean? Also this has been ongoing for several days so yes definitely have been through my whole pc restart as well.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes yes `from transformers import pipeline` gives above error. What do you mean use `python` in the console? Do you mean run the same command  `from transformers import pipeline`  in `python` command line??

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch  I can confirm I installed on `python 3` and also jupyter book was on `python 3`. Regardless when I verify in `jupyter` I can see `transformers` in the list as well

Comment: @ella Yes, "python console" and "python command line" mean the same thing here. This will help rule out some environment issues. Wayne and Nicholas' comments point to this same problem.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes `(py38) C:\Users\jy70622>from transformers import pipeline
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`  This command is invalid in python command line though.

Comment: `(py38) C:\Users\jy70622>python --version
Python 3.8.13`

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes i just ran `!python --version` in python command line, and `!python --version` in jupyterbook. Both shows `3.8.13` version

Comment: @ella The first is a CMD error. Do you have a teacher or mentor that you can sit with and work through these? I think there are several issues here, and continuing in the comments like this is unlikely to resolve all of them.

Comment: I don't.. I also tried to install transformers successfully in jupyter notebook. Added a screenshot above. In that way at least we can rule out the inconsistency between notebook and python. And again, issue not solved. This just doesn't make sense anymore/

Comment: There are two (or more) versions of Python installed.  `pip3` installed the transformers package for one version of Python, but the script is being executed from a different version of python that does not have the package installed.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes @NicholasHansen-Feruch I think its resolved now. I just tried to use `%pip install transformers==3.4.0`, instead of `!pip install transformers==3.4.0` in jupyte rbook, and it worked. I can proceed with the project for now. Although I don't know what I did wrong in my python command line earlier that caused the inconsistency. Thank you both

Comment: @JohnGordon Both Python command line and Jupyter notebook show version as `Python 3.8.13` and env as `py38`. anything else to check?

Comment: Run the command `pip3 show transformers` and note the Location directory.  Then inside Python (whichever version you like), run the code `import sys; print(sys.path)`, and compare the listed directories with the one you got from `pip3`.

Comment: @JohnGordon One is showing `C:\Users\jy70606\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Lib\site-packages`, and the other one showing `'C:\\Users\\jy70606\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py38\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\jy70606\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\jy70606\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\jy70606\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py38\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']` . seems to be same. I will open a new thread for this. Thanks for the help

Comment: There is a difference -- `lib` vs `Lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its resolved now. I just tried to use %pip install transformers==3.4.0, instead of !pip install transformers==3.4.0 in jupyter book, and it worked. I can proceed with the project for now. Although I don't know what I did wrong in my python command line earlier that caused the inconsistency. Will open a new thread.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern `%pip install` magic command (and related `%conda install` for those using conda for package management). Those magic commands were added to insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook you run them in. The exclamation alone doesn't do that, as explained at the top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Installing using `%pip` in Jupyter notebook will install the package to your root python installation. Probably not what you want if you are using virtual environments.

If you want to use the packages that you have installed in your virtual environment, you need to change the kernel that your notebook is using.
Have a look at this article [https://towardsdatascience.com/run-a-new-jupyter-notebook-in-an-already-existing-virtual-environment-7490b3dd5ab6#:~:text=Click%20](https://towardsdatascience.com/run-a-new-jupyter-notebook-in-an-already-existing-virtual-environment-7490b3dd5ab6#:%7E:text=Click%20)

You should run:

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=venv
```

where "venv" is the name of your virtual env.
Then restart your Jupyter kernel and go to the top, select "kernel" then "change kernel". You should see "venv" as an option.

Now all the packages that you installed in your virtual environment will be available to you in your Jupyter notebook